# What should the Brand Assets sizes be?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, size

I used to use Xcode 6.1.1, today I installed Xcode 7.3 beta 3, it gave some warnings, one of them was the 'Brand Assets' as the picture below.

I added my icons to AppIcon and everything is ok, but I don't know the sizes for "Brand Assets".

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From apple documentation:

> Large app icon. A 1280x768 point layered image used in the App Store.
>   
> Small app icon. A 400x240 point layered image used to represent your app on the home screen.
>   
> Top shelf image. A 1920x720 point image displayed when your app is selected in the Apple TV App Launcher.

For more information you can check apple documentation here: [Brand Assets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/BrandAssetsType.html)

Comment: This Answer is for tvOS, not iOS as indicated in the Question’s tags.